# If you went to bed earlier you would not be so tired

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If you went to bed earlier you would not be so tired

Which is the meaning of this sentence?

1. You didn't go to bed earlier and as a result you're tired.
2. You don't go to bed earlier and as a result you're tired.

Source Type 2 conditional : http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/

Comment: It could be either one, depending on context. You need to add some.

Comment: Because of the subordinating clause headed by "if", this is the "irrealis" use of the modal "would". It speaks of a "condition contrary to fact". A better phrasing is _"If you **had gone** to bed earlier you would not be so tired"_, and without context to the contrary, the first option is closest to the intended meaning. To say the same thing as in number 2), we could write: _"If you **go** to bed earlier you **won't** be so tired"_

Comment: I see , and what about what @JustAnotherPerson Said ? And I can't Add context it's from here http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/ Type 2 conditional.

Comment: Unfortunately, although I'm sure he or she has the best intentions, JustAnotherPerson has provided JustAnotherIncorrectAnswer.

Comment: By the way, you'll spare yourself a lot of grief if you forget all about "type 1", "type 2" etc. conditionals. There are many more than 3 "types" of conditionals. The "type N" stuff was invented by ESL teachers, and the nomeclature is unknown to everyone else.

Comment: I know ,  I try to avoid these grammar and conditional  rules and things but sometimes an english learner has to check them to see if someone is  talking about a hypothetical situation in the future or past or if he's simply talking about a fact in the past and its results in the present/future these sentences with if are confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

It means the second version.
If you'd like to create the sentence that would match the first version, you'd say it this way:
If you had gone to bed earlier you wouldn't be tired(now)

Comment: Ok thanks and this ? just to be sure If I won the lottery, I would be happy. ( 1- If win the lottery  I will be  happy but it's  unlikely that I will win the lottery / 2- I don't win the lottery , I'm not happy )

Comment: @VeryBadAtEnglish: I think I too could quite reasonably say that, even though I've never bought a lottery ticket ('cos I *might* buy a winning ticket in the future). But it wouldn't really make sense to say *If I **had** won I'd be rich,* since I was never in contention.

Comment: So it's (1) not (2) :)

Answer (score 0):

Either could be correct. In the past:

> I know you were working hard but you fell asleep during the meeting. You didn't go to bed earlier and as a result you're tired.

In the present:

> I wish you would get a job rather than sleep all afternoon. You don't go to bed earlier and as a result you're tired.

though these would read better with *early* rather than *earlier*, since we don't know what it is earlier than.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to say that you wouldn't be so tired *all the time* if only you would go to bed earlier:

> If you **went** to bed earlier, you **wouldn't be** so tired all the time.
>   or
>   If you **would go** to bed earlier, you **wouldn't be** so tired all the time.

If I wanted to say that you wouldn't be so tired *today* if you had gone to bed earlier last night:

> If you **had gone** to bed earlier, you **wouldn't be** so tired.

If I wanted to say that you would not have fallen asleep at the theater *two weeks ago* if you had gone to bed earlier *the night before*:

> If you **had gone** to bed earlier, you **wouldn't have been** so tired.